# Writing formula into an Excel Range with Option Strict On

Tags: vb.net, excel-2007

Is it possible to write formulas across a range in Excel from VB.Net? I'm using a String array to hold a list of formulas that I would like to apply to an Excel range, instead of looping through and writing them one at a time.

This line is what I am attempting to use to write to a range:

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("AF" & intCurrentRow.ToString & ":AG" & intCurrentRow.ToString).Formula = formulas
```

The formula is being written to Excel, but Excel is actually displaying the formula, instead of the calculated value. If I write each formula to each cell like this:

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("AF" & intCurrentRow.ToString).Formula = formulas(0)
xlWorkSheet.Range("AG" & intCurrentRow.ToString).Formula = formulas(1)
```

It works perfectly fine and Excel displays the calculated values as it should. Almost seems like I'm missing a step but I haven't been able to find anything in my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I hit post I figured out the problem. Instead of using the `.Formula` property of an Excel.Range, you have to use the `.FormulaArray` property instead.

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("AF" & intCurrentRow.ToString & ":AG" & intCurrentRow.ToString).FormulaArray = formulas
```